# Three.js: Exception when using THREE.JSONLoader.parse instead of THREE.JSONLoader.load

Tags: json, parsing, three.js

When I make a JSON model and load it using THREE.JSONLoader.load it is loaded without any issues, but when I attempt to make a variable out of it and include data in the main script the THREE.JSONLoader.parse call throws an exception.

```
var lh_model = {
    "metadata" : { "formatVersion" : 3.1, ..., "morphTargets"  : 0 },
    "vertices": [
          0.001000,    0.001000,  -0.001000,
        102.616974,  -61.974983,  19.303007,
        102.108978,  -62.482986,  -7.620989,
        123.952972,  -49.274994,  -3.048992,
        123.952972,  -48.766994,  14.223002
    ],
    "uvs": [0.9458,0.5134,0.9419,0.5177,0.9513,0.5177,........],
    "faces": [ 0, 4, 1, 2 ],
    "morphTargets": []
}

var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
var geometry = loader.parse(lh_model);
```

load.parse causes the

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

error somewhere deep inside of Three.js:

```
THREE.Mesh.prototype.updateMorphTargets = function () {

    if ( this.geometry.morphTargets.length > 0 ) {
```

The same happens when I take the working examples made by other people (http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Model.html).

I am using Three.js r.58

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
var model = loader.parse( lh_model );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( model.geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial() );
scene.add( mesh );
```

If your add a material into your model, you would do something like this

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( model.geometry, materials[ 0 ] );
```

three.js r.58

Comment: Note for all followers: pay attention to Three.js version. r.56 does not have `parse` method.